# Extend Flash messages' functionality on Rails ? Auto hide, embedded links ? Close button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, hyperlink, notifications, message

I have been using the default built in flash all over my app, but now I realized that I need to have some more functionality with it:
- I need the messages to auto hide avec a given number of seconds (specifiable for each message would be great)
- I need to have a little closing button, so the customer can get rid of it whenever
- I need to be able to add a simple href link in there that the user can click if he wants

Any good approach in doing this that won't make me go all over my code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily achieve this, I recently wrote a post doing exactly this. Checkout the post [here](http://syedaslam.com/2011/01/24/adding-close-flash-messages-rails/). If you are using jQuery then to automatically close the flash messages you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("div[id^='flash_']").fadeOut(3000);
});
```

You can learn more about jQuery wildcard selection from [here](http://rosshawkins.net/archive/2011/10/14/jquery-wildcard-selectors-some-simple-examples.aspx).

Comment: thanks, that works great. Any idea on how to display a link in there ?